# Pick up attachment from similarly named attachments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an attachment list in column "I" with an entry "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund **MW**".

There are other files in a folder with name
- "JUN2019_fund_MWMU" or
- "JUN2019_fund_MWMD"

I want to pick up "JUN2019_fund_**MW**"

I tried below code and get an error.

```
.Attachments.Add Pth & Dir(Pth & "*" & Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & "*")
```

Comment: You need to find some unique characters to Identify the File. That is both the names should have something unique in them to Match.

Comment: Yes, MW is unique word but problem is that there are file which has name JUN2019_fund_MWMU and JUN2019_fund_MWMD as well I want macro to pick up file "JUN2019_fund_MW" only

Comment: What is the Extention of the attachment?

Comment: all the attachments are .xls

Comment: Like this? `.Attachments.Add Pth & Dir(Pth & "*" & Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & ".xls")`

Comment: If `JUN2019_fund_` is constant then it will be even more easier to pick up the file. For example `.Attachments.Add Pth & "JUN2019_fund_" & Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & ".xls"`

Comment: Getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197483/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-khyati-dedhia).

Comment: This Should work. `.Attachments.Add Pth & Dir(Pth & "*" & Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & ".xls")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.Attachments.Add Pth & _
                 "JUN2019_fund_" & _
                 Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & _
                 ".xls"
```

A better way to handle it would be

```
Dim Atthfile As String

Atthfile = pth & _
           "JUN2019_fund_" & _
           Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & _
           ".xls"

'~~> If file is found, attach else continue without attaching
If Dir(Atthfile) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add Atthfile
```